# A very strange System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a strange error in my code...

Code:

```
public class PropertyCollection<T> : IDictionary<T, string>
{
        private Dictionary<T, string> dict;
        ...
        public string this[T key]
        {
            get
            {
                bool has_key = this.Keys.Any(x => x == key); 
                return this.dict[key];
            }
            set
            {
                this.dict[key] = value;
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

The first row

```
bool has_key = this.Keys.Any(x => x == key);
```

returns `true`.

But

```
return this.dict[key];
```

throws the error:

> System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

How this could be?

If I change the row, that throws an exception, to

```
return this.dict[this.Keys.First(x => x == key)];
```

everything becomes normal and there is now error.

Comment: just use dict.containskey

Comment: Doing this: `bool has_key = this.Keys.Any(x => x == key);` defeats the purpose of using a dictionary.

Comment: If you want us to help, post a small, complete, compiling reproduce of your problem.

Comment: What is `T` in this case?  Do you override `Equals` on `T`?  Did you also override `==`?  Does the `Dictionary<T, string>` use the default `EqualityComparer<T>` or a different one?  There are lots of reasons this could be the case. Some code demonstrating the issue would be useful.

Comment: `T` probably has a broken `GetHashCode()`

Comment: What is `this.Keys`? You appear to be confusing `this.Keys` with `this.dict.Keys`. They aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Well, in your code you don't use Dictionary<T1, T2> collection in a proper way. So google for how to use it and read some information about this matter. If you'll still have some problem - create short but complete example of your problem and post it to SO

Comment: Also, why is `x == key` allowed when the right-hand side `key` has type `T` which is a type parameter without any contraints? Are you hiding some constraint from us?

Comment: First few comments are strange)
bool has_key = this.Keys.Any(x => x == key); - are givin just to look what is going on, of cause.

Comment: @BigMan First few comments must have been posted before the posters have finished reading your question.

Comment: `T` has override the `==` and `EqualityComparer<T>`

Comment: What is the result of `this.dict.Keys.Any(x => x == key)`?

Comment: @BigMan well show some code that tells us what you are overriding and how you are doing it.  It's likely this that causes the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `T` overrides both `Equals` and `GetHashCode`<sup>*</sup>, the only way I could thing how this would happen is if your key is *mutable*, its `GetHashCode` method uses mutable fields, and you called a mutating method *after* the key has been inserted into the dictionary.

This would make the linear search `this.Keys.Any(x => x == key)` produce `true`, but hash-based search would produce an exception.

Confirming this is very easy: the code below should print `false`:

```
var first = dict.Keys.First(x => x == key);
Console.WriteLine(first.GetHashCode() == key.GetHashCode());
```

<sup>*</sup> If `T` does not override one or both these methods, [see this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/371328/335858).

Comment: Another possibility is that `==` and `Equals` have different semantics for the relevant type `T`.

Comment: Or the classical one: `T` overrides `Equals`, but it does not override `GetHashCode`, or that override calls `base.GetHashCode` or is incorrect in some other way.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, that's very likely too. I edited to mention a related Q&A.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `T` overrides both `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and even `==` and `!=`, but `GetHashCode` was `return base.GetHashCode() `
My mistake. I am ashamed for this stupid error(

Comment: This code overrides `GetHashCode()` but fails from mutability: `using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
sealed class MuatbleInt
{
public int Val { get; set; }
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
var other = obj as MuatbleInt;
return (object)other != (object)null && other.Val == Val;
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
return Val;
}
internal static void Main()
{
var key = new MuatbleInt { Val = 42, };
var dict = new Dictionary<MuatbleInt, string> { { key, "" }, };
key.Val = 666;
var hasKey = dict.Keys.Any(key.Equals);
var bang = dict[key];
}
}`